# Lenovo b570 Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 wireless doesn't work

Tags: 11.10, wireless, networking, broadcom

```
prumar@bluelaptop:~$ rfkill list
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
2: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller [14e4:4727] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Broadcom Corporation Device [14e4:051b]
```

I don't know what to do. I am really upset, because after trying everything the issue still remain.

Please,Do anyone can help me?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same wireless card on a Lenovo U160 and I got it working by

`gksu gedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`

and adding

`blacklist acer_wmi`

to to the end of the file.
Restart your computer and hopefully your wireless works. Maybe you have to press Fn+F5 (the wireless activation key combination) once or twice, but for me it just worked instantly after rebooting.

Comment: I did it, acer_wmi is already in the blacklist, but wireless dones't work. The Ubuntu version is 11.10 and the version kernel is 3.0.0-12-generic-pae.