# Levono b570 can't enable wlan

Tags: networking, wireless, lenovo, internet-connection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Lenovo b570 Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 wireless doesn't work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66848/lenovo-b570-broadcom-corporation-bcm4313-wireless-doesnt-work)

I´ve got the following problem on my new notebook:

I installed Ubuntu 11.10 and I can not enable wireless connection on network panel.

I´m on the network panel (part of system panel) and cant switch the on/off button from "off" to "on" because it jumps instantly back to "off"

I don't know what to do, because I already had a stable wlan connection - 2 times... But I don't know what I´ve done to fix it.

I have got no Windows or other OS on my notebook.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix the problem doing the following:

Open a Terminal window. Type:

```
sudo rfkill list
```

If you get:

```
0: acer-wireless Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: yes
        Hard blocked: no
```

Go to `/etc/modprobe.d`

Edit the file with root privileges:

```
sudo nano blacklist.conf
```

Add the line to disable it:

```
blacklist acer-wmi
```