# Can't connect to Wireless Broadcom BCM4312, using wifi

Tags: wireless, broadcom, wifi-hardware-switch

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Wireless doesn't work on a Broadcom BCM4312](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125529/wireless-doesnt-work-on-a-broadcom-bcm4312)

I have a problem connecting my Dell Vostro 1520 to wireless internet. Output of `rfkill`:

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth 
   Soft blocked: no 
   Hard blocked: no 
1: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN 
   Soft blocked: no 
   Hard blocked: no 
2: dell-wifi: Wireless LAN 
   Soft blocked: yes 
   Hard blocked: yes 
3: dell-bluetooth: Bluetooth 
   Soft blocked: no 
   Hard blocked: no
```

I've tried other solutions like `/etc/modprobe.d$ sudo gedit blacklist.conf` and blacklisting the 43xx part, also tried getting `sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer` and `sudo apt-get install b43-fwcutter` and at last I've tried installing th privative(?) drivers for the Wireless Card. (Broadcom STA Wireless Driver), with following result for `lspci`:

```
0e:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY (rev 01)
```

It's obvious I've the switch turned [on], but it says that wireless is disabled by hardware switch and when I enter "System Settings -▸ Network -▸ Airplane Mode" it is turned [on] and when I turn it [off] and try to turn [on] the Wireless button, it goes to [off] position automatically.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Please see - http://askubuntu.com/q/125529/35775

Answer (score 1):

You need to install either "b43-fwcutter/firmware-b43-installer" or "Broadcom STA proprietary restricted driver).

Try the first response in the link : [How do I get a Broadcom BCM4313 wireless card working?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/127633/how-do-i-get-a-broadcom-bcm4313-wireless-card-working)
Make sure Broadcom STA restricted driver is purged => "sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source broadcom-sta-common broadcom-sta-source".

I had the same issue, and in my case the Broadcom card is 4327, which is troublesome and works only with Broadcom restricted driver. The broadcom restricted driver is buggy , and freezes the screen. I wouldn't recommend this approach.