# 12.04 does not detect wlan0(Broadcom  4365)

Tags: 12.04, wireless, drivers, bluetooth

Installed 12.04 on dell inspiron 5420.  wired connection is working however wifi and bluetooth connection does not work. In fact I can't see wlan0. Can I know the correct driver to install?

Comment: You could start by typing 'lspci' in a terminal to know which Broadcom card you have.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/127633/how-do-i-get-a-broadcom-bcm4313-wireless-card-working

Comment: result of lspci                                              02:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation Device 4365 (rev 01)

Comment: is it solved? did you look at the link?

Comment: i tried but the acces was denied..

Comment: Did you check the hardware switch?

Answer (score 0):

it's the driver issue, the broadcom didn't release the driver source.
some guy extracted a amd64 binary version from Dell's pre-loaded Ubuntu. 
follow this link to see more.
https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=145884

Answer (score -1):

[ubuntu-1204-wifi-not-working-at-laptop-or-notebook-unblock-it](http://www.iasptk.com/ubuntu/19593-ubuntu-1204-wifi-not-working-at-laptop-or-notebook-unblock-it)

**Ubuntu 12.04.  WiFi not working**

Check if the wifi card is blocked (Terminal)

`rfkill list wlan`     (for wifi)

OR

`rfkill list all`             (for wifi and bluetooth)

UNBLOCK:

`rfkill unblock wlan`     (for wifi)

OR

`rfkill unblock all`             (for wifi and bluetooth)

Restart the network:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```