# My computer can't connect to my WIFI

Tags: wireless, drivers

I am incredibly new to using Linux of any kind. I'm trying this on my netbook just to learn what it is about, and I'm really struggling with getting it connected to the Wifi.

I have just installed Ubuntu 12.0 on it. I've replaced Windows altogether so it's not a dual-boot or anything. I was able to connect using an Ethernet cable to get it up and running, but my Wifi just will not connect. Instead of the Wifi symbol I have a little computer monitor.

It behaves as if it is connected, but it does not let me use Firefox to browse anything at all.  I have been scouring forums and using the help in Ubuntu but it all looks very confusing to me, and I'm afraid of breaking something since I'm not sure what I am doing.

Does anyone have any help for me at all? I'm kind of at my wit's end...

Comment: What model of netbook do you have?

Comment: Lenovo S10 Netbook

Answer (score 0):

A list of reported issues with the **Lenovo S10** can be found on the [Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupport/Machines/Netbooks#Lenovo_S10). According to that, you may install the restricted non-free drivers to make wireless function properly.

You can look at [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/127660/14368) for help installing Broadcom 43** drivers... Which is what I believe your netbook has (not sure, though).

Comment: Oh! I kept searching for Wifi issues specifically, didn't think to look into the netbook itself. I will look into that and let you know if it helps. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The Lenovo S10 netbook is listed as having: "Wireless networking: Broadcom 802.11b/g Wi-Fi".
This is older technology, and if the wireless network you are trying to connect to is set to 802.11n only, you may have trouble.
Normally, though, the network manager program will at least let you see available networks.
Sounds like first of all you need to determine if the OS can see the hardware in the netbook.
Open a terminal (Accessories -> Terminal), and type and enter: "ifconfig".
This is a command which will display a list of devices in your netbook. What you are looking for is one on the left-hand side labeled "wlan0" or similar (shorthand for Wireless Local Area Network number 0). If you can see this, then this narrows it down to probably a driver issue, which can usually be fixed. If you cannot see anything indicating a wireless network device, then you may have to invest in a new plug-in USB wireless adapter which will almost certainly be recognised.