# How to install wireless drivers for my laptop

Tags: compaq

I'm having problem installing wireless driver in my Compaq CQ 43. PCI ID is BCM4313 and I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTE 64 bit operating system. Please somesone help me. I'm a newby so I'm kinda new in Linux system.

Thanks in advance,
Engg. Saif

Comment: Read this first: http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers

Comment: most complete answer that specifically deals with the chip you have is here: http://askubuntu.com/a/127660/237241