# Wireless Networks not showing up!

Tags: 12.04, networking, drivers, broadcom

I am using Ubuntu 12.04. I am new to Ubuntu.
When I click on the internet icon in the upper-right-hand corner, it doesn't show any wireless networks under "wireless networks."

I went to Additional Drivers and found out that 'Broadcom STA wireless driver' is activated and currently in use.
I searched internet but all the answers would tell me to install wireless driver which I already have.
What might be the issue here? How can I troubleshoot the issue?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos

Comment: @MostafaAhangarha Thank you for the link. Answer from antivirtel solved my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue by using the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install broadcom-sta-common
sudo reboot
```

This is an answer from @antivirtel from this question:
[How do I get a Broadcom BCM4313 wireless card working?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/127633/how-do-i-get-a-broadcom-bcm4313-wireless-card-working)